# Slowing down a nonlinear differential system to compute its asymptotics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we solve following system of differential equations.

$$x'(t)=- \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}[\lambda y-\frac{1}{2}(1+\lambda)x+1-x-y]$$

$$y'(t)= \frac{x}{2}[-\lambda y+\frac{1}{2}x]$$

$$x(0)= \frac{2 \lambda}{(1+\lambda)^2},y(0)= \frac{1}{(1+\lambda)^2}$$

In text book it given that the asymptotic value of $x(t)$ is 
$$x(t= \infty)= \frac{1-\lambda}{1+\lambda}$$
Can some one help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: the solution looks ugly

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner at least asymptotic limit.

Comment: @Kumar Excellent remark: explicitly solving a differential system is not the only approach to get quite specific informations about its behaviour (actually, despite what classroom examples could make believe, the cases where one can get an explicit solution are, in "real life", rather rare).

Comment: What is this textbook?

Comment: @ Did This is not from a text book. My instructor is given some material to read ( on statistical physics). where they have not explained these things directly. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Once supplemented by some missing hypothesis and cleansed of some unfortunate misprints, the exercise is a nice conceptual question about the trajectories of a given system in two different time scales.

Let $X(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\ y(t)\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}3+\lambda&2(1-\lambda)\\ -1&2\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ then the system of differential equations in the question can be rewritten as $$X'(t)=-\tfrac14x(t)\cdot A\cdot X(t).$$ Consider the solution $U(t)=\begin{pmatrix}u(t)\\ v(t)\end{pmatrix}$ of the differential system $$U'(t)=-A\cdot U(t),$$ with the same initial condition $U(0)=X(0)$, then $X(t)=U(\theta(t))$ where $\theta$ solves $$\theta'(t)=\tfrac14x(t),\qquad\theta(0)=0.$$ In other words, $X$ and $U$ follow the same path but in two different time scales. Furthermore, if $U(t)$ crosses the line $u=0$ for the first time at some point $(0,v_*)$, then $\theta'(t)=0$ at that time hence, due to the time change, $X(t)$ *accumulates* on this point in the sense that $X(t)\to(0,v_*)$ when $t\to+\infty$, in particular, $$y(t)\to y_\infty=v_*.$$
One sees that the change of time scale is quite drastic since it leads to $X$ staying confined to a strict subset of the whole path of $U$, and that *the exercise should ask to show that $y(t)\to y_\infty$ (not that $x(t)\to y_\infty$ which is absurd since $x(t)\to0$, as explained above).*

To go further, note that 
*a missing hypothesis is that $\lambda$ is in $(0,1)$*.

The eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are $a=\lambda+1$, with eigenvector $V_a=\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$, and $b=2(\lambda+1)$, with eigenvector $V_b=\begin{pmatrix}2\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$,
hence, for every $t$, $$U(t)=c_ae_a(t)V_a+c_be_b(t)V_b,\qquad e_a(t)=\mathrm e^{-at},\qquad e_b(t)=\mathrm e^{-bt},$$ for some suitable constants $c_a$ and $c_b$. 
The initial condition $a^2X(0)=\begin{pmatrix}2\lambda\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ implies that $a^2U(0)=-2V_a+V_b$, hence, for every $t$, $$a^2U(t)=-2e_a(t)V_a+e_b(t)V_b.$$
In particular, $$a^2u(t)=-2(1-\lambda)e_a(t)+2e_b(t)=2e_a(t)\cdot(e_a(t)-(1-\lambda)),$$ hence $u(t)=0$ for the first time when $$e_a(t)=1-\lambda.$$ Finally, note that, for every $t$, $$a^2v(t)=2e_a(t)-e_b(t)=e_a(t)\cdot(2-e_a(t)),$$ hence, when $u(t)=0$, $a^2v(t)=(1-\lambda)(1+\lambda)$, that is, $$v_*=y_\infty=\frac{1-\lambda}{1+\lambda}.$$

---

**Supplementary material:** Below is a plot of the curve $(U(t))_{t\geqslant0}$ starting from $U(0)=\frac1{(1+\lambda)^2}\begin{pmatrix}2\lambda\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ for $\lambda=\frac12$. The curve $(X(t))_{t\geqslant0}$ starting from $X(0)=U(0)$ is the part of the curve on the right of the ordinate axis $x=0$. The point $(0,y_*)$ is $(0,\frac13)$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image: The case $\lambda=\frac12$]

$$\texttt{ParametricPlot[{4s(2s-1)/9,4s(2-s)/9},{s,0,1}]}$$

For every $\lambda$, $U(t)$ and $X(t)$ stay on the part of parabola with equation $$(1+\lambda)(x+2y)^2=4(x+(1-\lambda)y).$$
The parabola when $\lambda=\frac12$:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

$$\texttt{graph[3(x+2y)^2=4(2x+y),{x,-.2,4},{y,-0.5,0.5}]}$$

Finally, one can generalize these results to every starting point, noting that the dynamics of $(u,v)$ is conveniently encoded by the variables $(w,z)$ defined by $$w=u+(1-\lambda)v,\qquad z=(u+2v)^2,$$ since $$w'=-2(1+\lambda)w,\qquad z'=-2(1+\lambda)z.$$
As a direct consequence, starting from some $(w_0,z_0)$, one stays on the $(w,z)$-parabola of equation $$w_0\,z(t)-z_0\,w(t)=0,$$ thus, for every starting point $(x_0,y_0)$, the solution $(x(t),y(t))$ stays on the parabola
$$
(x_0+(1-\lambda)y_0)\cdot(x+2y)^2-(x_0+2y_0)^2\cdot(x+(1-\lambda)y)=0,$$ and $(x(t),y(t))\to(0,y_\infty)$ when $t\to+\infty$, with
$$
y_\infty=\frac{(1-\lambda)\cdot(x_0+2y_0)^2}{4\cdot(x_0+(1-\lambda)y_0)}.$$

Comment: @ Did Thanks for help. I have small question, In one of the other exercise (similar to this) I have $X'(t)=\tfrac38x(t)\cdot A\cdot X(t) + W(t)$. where $W(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\ y(t)\end{pmatrix}$. In this case how do we find asymptotic solution.

Comment: Thus W = X ? I don't know, I am afraid you have to be more specific here.

Comment: Sorry, This is the problem.
$y'(t)= \frac{3}{8} x [-2\lambda y+x]$, 
$x'(t)= \frac{3}{8} x [-2(\lambda-1) y-(\lambda+3)x]+\frac{x}{2}$

Comment: Thus, $X'(t)=\frac38x(t)(A\cdot X(t)+B)$. Then yes, $X$ follows the solutions $U$ of the system $U'(t)=A\cdot U(t)+B$, and the trajectory of $X$ stops at the first point on the trajectory of $U$ such that $u=0$, if any.